# What Christians believe about Time Travel and Teleportation?

Tags: science

I have three question:

1. Is teleportation is phenomena that is proven in the Bible?
2. Do Time Travel is possible (e.g. Forward Time Travel) is generally accepted fact in the Bible?
3. Can the Fouth Dimension be attributed to the Spiritual world?

To date, scientist have been digging the possibilities of telporation, using quantum computers to try to "teleport" small particles, from what I've read with science articles, they managed to teleport small particles (*I don't have the citation but it can be Google'd pretty easily*)

1. I've read some scriptures pertaining such "teleportation" for example, Angelical beings showing and disappearing from places to places, Jesus Christ after the death on the cross showing from places to places, with people witnessing.
2. I've read scriptures from both the Old and New Testaments that prophets from Isaiah to John seeing into the future revealing what's ahead of the world. Is this is a form of traveling through time seeing the future or it is just a masterly calculated effects of events. What I mean is, if the future that have been seen is a reality that will happen thus linked to our present and not just a precalculated effect of the actions of the  world? For example, if I have a ball and I am really a good shooter, I can predict that when I throw the ball at the right angle and right force it will shoot, but I  that does not mean it will happen surely. The future is something that if you have seen or known, regardless of what you do, you will not be able to change it, but in the case of shooting the ball, although I know it will shoot but it's not the future so I can choose not to shoot at all, then the precalculated outcome I have for it will not longer be valid.
3. We live in a 3D spatial world, and we see in 2D (two dimension), if we are placed in a 2D spatial world, as a 3-dimentional being we can easily jump around any point in the 2D spatial world, like a mysterious being. Now, if we are living in the 4D spatial world, we can see in 3D and just as similar, we can jump around any "point" in the 3D world, like instantly go to point A to point B, without traversing the 3D spatial world. Is the Spiritual world considered a Fourth Dimension?

Comment: Is this a scientifically proven ability?

Comment: @ken-graham Yes from what was reported teleportation of small partiacles has been made by IBM (Here's the link: https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_group.php?id=2862)

Comment: Here's another link with title "Is teleportation possible? Yes, in the quantum world" https://www.nsf.gov/discoveries/disc_summ.jsp?cntn_id=300854&org=NSF&from=news

Comment: One would need to conduct some sort of survey in order to answer this question. "What (do) Christians believe (about obscure, non-proven, hypothetical theories) ?" Or else, one could just guess the answer and express an opinion about the end result.

Comment: I have updated the 3 question to prevent the opinionated question.

Comment: I don't know about time travel, but there's [teleportation in the New Testament](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+8:39-40&version=RSV) 
(apparently).

Comment: Indeed, [here's an article](https://trivialdevotion.blogspot.com/2012/08/philip-teleports-acts-839-40.html) that discusses many instances of apparent teleportation or something like it in the Old and New Testaments.

Comment: @Fireburn, that IBM link contains an amazingly incorrect statement: "*According to the uncertainty principle, the more accurately an object is scanned, the more it is disturbed by the scanning process*".  Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) knows better: "*Historically, the uncertainty principle has been confused with a related effect in physics, called the observer effect, which notes that measurements of certain systems cannot be made without affecting the system*".

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing in the doctrine of any significant Christian group about time travel, teleportation or the "fourth dimension". Christians are therefore free to believe whatever seems correct to them about these things.

There are scriptural descriptions of events that appear to be translation of people faster than is normally occurring. This might be considered teleportation. However these events are miraculous, and so not covered by the normal physical laws.

"Seeing the future" is not the same as time travel.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question to get a general answer.